# Is there any solution to addition integer in a string in PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add integer in a sting. Like

```
$string = "1XYZ";
$int = 1;
$result = $int+$string;
//output should be
2XYZ
// but its return only 2 without string (XYZ)
```

how can i solve this problem in PHP? I Also need a solution for SQL query for the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both in PHP and SQL you would have to separate the int from string with string functions or use regex

Comment: Read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

A non regex solution.

You can use the type cast in php to transform the string in to the integer.
Then use str_replace to get the string from the string.

Then it's just a matter of adding the ints and concatenate the string.

This works because the integer is at the left in the string, and because of that type casting will truncate the string part of the string.

```
$string = "1XYZ";
$int = 1;

$start_int = (int) $string; // 1
$start_str = str_replace($start_int, "", $string); // XYZ

$result = $int+$start_int . $start_str; // 1 + 1 . XYZ
echo $result; // 2XYZ
```

https://3v4l.org/SGSFC